# Power Fist tools not showing up

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

Tried the [Power Fist](http://wiki.technicpack.net/Power_Gauntlet) from the [Modular Powersuits](http://wiki.technicpack.net/Modular_Powersuits) mod in Tekkit 1.1.10 (MC 1.5.2) for the first time today. Installed all the basic tools:

- Axe
- Pickaxe
- Shovel
- Shears
- Rototiller
- Field Tinker Module
- In-Place Assembler

However when I select the Power Fist in my toolbar and scroll through its tools, all I get to use is:

- Shears
- Rototiller
- Field Tinker Module
- In-Place Assembler

What's going on? Where are the rest? What am I doing wrong? Have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I did miss something. The rest of the tools are actually always active through left-click already. The tool cycling is just for the right-click action.